# why i getting a error "Unresolved reference: fillMaxSize" with modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-design-library, android-jetpack-compose-material3

i am trying to use the jetpack compose but it giving so much errors, one of them is that -

```
package com.example.imagecardcompose

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            

        }
    }

    @Preview
    @Composable
    fun Display() {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()  // here i getting this error

        ) {
            Text(
                text = "vishwas",
                color = Color.Red)
            Text(text = "vishnu")
            Text(text = "babar")
        }
    }

}
```

error is "Unresolved reference: fillMaxSize".

i checked all my syntax so many times but i not fount any syntax error, please tell me how to use modifiers correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the wrong import. Please replace `import java.lang.reflect.Modifier` with `import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier`